# common elements in array with its index

Tags: java

I have two array

```
array1 = {1,2,1,3,5,2}
array2 = {a,b,c,d,e,f}
```

There are some common placed in array called "1,2" at location (0,1,3,5) and there are some correspondent values are placed in array2 means for 1 value is "a" so on.

So i need to check if is there any common value placed in array1, check its location and get the value from array2 on same location

**As there are two elements (1,2) common in array1 and its locations are (0,1,3,5).

Output would be : a,b,d,f

```
String test = "1$2$1$3$5$2";
    String[] strArray = test.split("\\$");
    StringBuilder ste = new StringBuilder();
    HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
    String str2 = "a$b$c$d$e$f";
    String[] strArray1 = str2.split("\\$");

    for(int i = 0; i < strArray.length ; i++)
    {
        if(set.add(strArray[i]) == false)
        {
            ste.append(strArray1[i]).append(",");

        }
    }
```

it doesnt display the right result. any idea?

Comment: Can you include where you declare and assign the arrays in your actual code? It seems that your array variable names don't match the code you give. It is hard to follow.

Comment: "it doesnt work fine" - what does that mean?

Comment: Also index 3 of array1 is the value "3". Did you mean (0,1,2,5)

Answer (score 0):

You want the output to contain all elements from `array2` that are duplicates in `array1`. But your algorithm adds each element in turn to a set and then tests for failure (due to a pre-existing item that is `equal`). This `add` operation won't fail until the second duplicate is added - it will not detect the first duplicate at all.

Here's a Java 8 solution that will detect all duplicates (and cope with different length arrays):

```
int[] array1 = {1, 2, 1, 3, 5, 2};
String[] array2 = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"};

String duplicate = IntStream.range(0, Math.min(array1.length, array2.length))
    .filter(n -> Arrays.stream(array1).filter(v -> v == array1[n]).count() > 1)
    .mapToObj(n -> array2[n])
    .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want more efficient Stream API solution than proposed by @sprinter (which is O(n^2)), you may try this:

```
int[] array1 = {1, 2, 1, 3, 5, 2};
String[] array2 = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"};

String result = IntStream.range(0, array1.length).boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> array1[i]))
        .values().stream().filter(list -> list.size() > 1).flatMap(List::stream)
        .map(idx -> array2[idx]).collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

Here we first create an intermediate map which keys are elements from `array1` and elements are lists of corresponding indices. Then we create another stream from the values and take only lists which have more than one index. Then we flatten all these lists, map to the corresponding `array2` values and join them together.